# Is it better to write data to a file in real time, or at program shutdown?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I'm developing an MMORPG and just want to hear the two different arguments between storing information (in this case game logs) to a file.

Would it be better to output the information as it gets created into a file (we're talking possibly 10-30 entries every couple seconds, or store it in memory until the program is shutting down, and then dump all the information into a file before it terminates.

I can see arguments for both ends mainly being if we keep it in memory, it will begin to take up a lot of resources on the computers end, and if we wait until the program shuts down and for whatever reason the program shuts down via a crash and the information isn't saved this would be quite bad in an MMORPG stand point... As well on the other side, I'm sure writing to a file every that often can't be very efficient either...

I'm doing all this in C++.

Comment: If your program crashes, you lose your logs. Which may be the only place you dump information that tell you why it crashes...

Comment: Don't worry about it.  The operating system will buffer most of your writes in memory anyway (unless you are syncing the disk), so your 20-30 writes "every few seconds" will not translate into a significant burden on the platters.  Unless and until you actually observe a problem, you shouldn't worry about the efficiency of your disk writes.  Write the data to disk as soon as you can.

Answer (score 4):

It may make sense to cache a few log messages, but storing it all until shutdown is a no-go.

First, MMOs tend to run for hours, and in a game you don't have that kind of memory to waste.

Second, and more importantly, logs are important for debugging. If your game crashes, you want those logs. If you cache them in memory and your game crashes, they're gone.